# Can you recommend a JQuery plugin that will display a calendar widget?

Tags: javascript, jquery, calendar, datepicker, widget

I don't need a datepicker or a scheduling calendar. I just need to be able to show a small calendar widget with a set of dates highlighted.

Answer (score 3):

You should try fullcalendar

http://arshaw.com/fullcalendar/

Comment: +1 very little functionality out of the box which is uncommon for a calendar widget.

Answer (score 2):

the jQuery UI has a full-featured Date Picker. Demo [here.](http://jqueryui.com/demos/datepicker/)

Edit: Oops didn't read your question correctly.

Comment: Yeah, I took a look at that but I couldn't figure out how to get around not having a picker. I just need to select an arbitrary range of time to display on the calendar and highlight a few dates. No need to be interactive.